# Multiple HtmlWebpackPlugins with webpack DevServer

Tags: javascript, webpack

You can use multiple `HtmlWebpackPlugin` plugins to create more than one HTML file in production, but only one of the HTML files will be used by the DevServer. Is there any way to use all the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` plugins in development as well?

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/main.js',
    anotherEntry: './src/anotherEntry.js'
  },
  // This only serves the index.html file on 404 responses
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: './src/main.html',
      chunks: ['main'],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'anotherEntry.html',
      template: './src/anotherEntry.html',
      chunks: ['anotherEntry'],
    }),
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`historyApiFallback` can be given manual `rewrites` to control in a more fine-grained manner what the DevServer should fallback to on `404` responses. This way we can serve the other files in development as well.

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/main.js',
    anotherEntry: './src/anotherEntry.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    historyApiFallback: {
      rewrites: [
        { from: /^\/anotherEntry/, to: '/anotherEntry.html' },
        { to: '/index.html' },
      ],
    },
    port: 3000,
  },
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: './src/main.html',
      chunks: ['main'],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'anotherEntry.html',
      template: './src/anotherEntry.html',
      chunks: ['anotherEntry'],
    }),
  ]
};
```